# Android: Want to go in next field automatically when item has been selected from list view

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

In my app, I have details layout, in which there is a list view which have card type. Below to that I have edittext. My requirement is, once I have selected an item in card type list view, the text indicator should automatically go into the next field i.e. edit text, but not getting idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field where you want to reach automatically should gain focus....

write this code inside your item clicked listener:

ex: let that field be edit text

so write : `edittext.requestFocus();`

Answer (score 0):

We have to initialize edit text in Onitem click listner.or in adapter

ex: 
    `listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {`

```
 @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            EditText mEditext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.demoEdit);
        }
    });

 /*(Or in adapter ) */convertview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            private int pos = position;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                              EditText mEditext = (EditText )findViewById(R.id.demoEdit);
            }
        });
```